# Custom actions in phone call log

Tags: android, logging, phone-call

Is there possibility to add some custom actions to Android phone calls log? For example, user is entering to phone calls log, make long tap on some item and standard context menu appears. I need to add item like "bill call" to this context menu. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only change the call log application by building your own firmware.

The call log is exposed via the `CallLog` content provider, though, so you can create your own billing-enhanced call log application, if you wish.